# Open MS Access 2007 (accdb/accde) forms within a browser

Tags: web-applications, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 accdb application that has few forms and the tables are present in SQL server (linked tables ) , I am trying to change the way my users will launch this application,
I would keep it in shared folder , and would like to provide an URL to the users which will have a button to launch my application , as soon as they click on it ,i would love to see the access application getting opened within the frame of browser.
Is it feasible? , I tried making it an accde file and got struck afterwards.